# How to configure Fedora 29 to use ruby 'number-theory' gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fedora, stdint, narray

So basically [RubyNumberTheory](https://github.com/dannysiu392005/ruby-number-theory) require the NArray gem, and it seems it requires some native compilation tools and probably some additional configuration. So on a Fedora 29, here is what was tried

```
$ gem install narray 
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing narray:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
[…]
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I did installed a few packages, through dnf like `gcc ruby-devel rubygems` and `group install "C Development Tools and Libraries"`and even some more unexpected `arm-none-eabi-newlib`. Actually, the header seems well installed on the system

```
$ whereis stdint.h
stdint: /usr/include/stdint.h
```

Even with environment variable set as following:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/include
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/include
```

The gem still won't install, telling stdint.h wasn't found. What else could be attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the `mkmf.log` file, it appeared the system was lacking `redhat-hardened-cc1`, so a simple `sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config` fixed that.